# Normal coordinates for harmonic approximation (classical lattice vibration)

Tags: classical-mechanics, condensed-matter

I am reading Jenő Sólyom's "Fundamentals of the Physcs of Solids" vol. 1. and i am very much stuck at this point (chapter 11.3.2 in the book):

In the harmonic approximation the potential energy of a lattice with a base can be written as:

$$U_{harm}= {1 \over 2} \sum \limits_{m, \mu, \alpha,  n, \nu, \beta}  \Phi^{\mu \nu}_{\alpha,\beta}(m-n) u_\alpha(m,\mu) u_\beta(n,\nu)  $$

Here $m,n$ sum primitive cells, $\mu,\nu$ base atoms and $\alpha,\beta$ coordinates.

We want to express this in the normal coordinates of the Fourier transform of $\Phi^{\mu \nu}(m-n)$, called the dynamical matrix $D$ and the instantatious displacements $u_\alpha(m,\mu,t)$ expressed in the eigenvectors $e^{(\lambda)}$ of $D$ in the normal coordinates $Q$:

$$D^{\mu \nu}_{\alpha,\beta}( \vec q)={1 \over \sqrt{M_\mu M_\nu}}\sum_n \Phi^{\mu \nu}(m-n)e^{-i\vec q ( \vec R_m -\vec R_n)}$$

$$u_\alpha(m,\mu,t)={1 \over \sqrt{N M_\mu}} \sum \limits_{ \vec q , \lambda}e^{(\lambda)}_{\mu,\alpha}(\vec q)Q_\lambda(\vec q) e^{i \vec q \vec R_m} $$

Putting the $u_\alpha(m,\mu,t)$  in the equation for $U_{harm}$ gives the expression of my concern:

$$U_{harm}={1 \over 2} \sum \limits_{m, \mu, \alpha,  n, \nu, \beta}  \Phi^{\mu \nu}_{\alpha,\beta}(m-n){1 \over \sqrt{N M_\mu}} \sum \limits_{ \vec q , \lambda}e^{(\lambda)}_{\mu,\alpha}(\vec q)Q_\lambda(\vec q) e^{i \vec q \vec R_m} {1 \over \sqrt{N M_\nu}} \sum \limits_{ \vec q' , \lambda}e^{(\lambda')}_{\nu,\alpha}(\vec q')Q_{\lambda'}(\vec q') e^{i \vec q' \vec R_n} $$

The argument now goes that in the secons sum only summants with $\vec q' = \vec q $   contribute because $\Phi^{\mu \nu}(m-n)$ only depends on the difference in lattice vectors $\vec R_m$ i really don't get this and would very much appriciate an explanation of this arument or the fact tat only these summants contribute.

PS: as always any critique and questions that make it easyer for you to answer the question is apriciated.

Comment: It occured to me that all this is maybe not necessary. We know that $D$ is diagonalizable so we know we can write $u_\alpha(\vec q,t)={1 \over \sqrt{N M_\mu}} \sum \limits_{ \lambda}e^{(\lambda)}_{\mu,\alpha}(\vec q)Q_\lambda(\vec q)$ and we know that in the base of eigenvectors $U_{harm}$ can be written as $U_{harm}={1 \over 2} \sum \limits_{\vec q, \lambda} \omega^2(\vec q) Q^*_\lambda(\vec q) Q_\lambda(\vec q)$ Does this make sense?